# Mule db component Input payload from another db query

Tags: java, database, mule, mule-flow

I need a basic Mule flow in order to select rows from one database, transform the payload and call a procedure in another database. I don't want to use DataMapper component, I would like to use Java Transformer instead.

My XML flow:

```
<set-variable variableName="currentOrder" value="#[payload.increment_id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="GET ORDER">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select id from sales where id=#[currentOrder]]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
<custom-transformer class="com.mycompany.transformers.TargerProc" doc:name="Java"/>
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="PROC1">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[call proc1(:P1,:P2)]]></db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="P1" type="NUMERIC" value="#[payload.id]"/>
    <db:out-param name="P2" type="NUMERIC" value=""/>
</db:stored-procedure>
```

First problem:

```
Message payload is of type: CaseInsensitiveHashMap
```

Could someone shed some light on this? I think it is really simple to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `<db:parameterized-query>{ call proc1(:P1,:P2) }</db:parameterized-query>` :-

```
<set-variable variableName="currentOrder" value="#[payload.increment_id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="GET ORDER">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select id from sales where id=#[currentOrder]]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
<custom-transformer class="com.mycompany.transformers.TargerProc" doc:name="Java"/>
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="PROC1">
    <db:parameterized-query>{ call proc1(:P1,:P2) }</db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="P1" type="NUMERIC" value="#[payload.id]"/>
    <db:out-param name="P2" type="NUMERIC" value=""/>
</db:stored-procedure>
```

Comment: :( no lucky. Could you help me understand the object type that I need to return inside Java transformer? Let me share my issue. I need to read the payload returned from MySQL and apply some rules, like remove special chars, change some values before send set the procedure parameter, etc. Thank you very much for your answer, I will try all your advices.

Comment: You need to return Object from your Java class as the DB expects an object

Comment: I've tested with Map and worked. Thanks again for your support ;)